# Send and receive messages on same port? Peer to peer message app python

Tags: python, sockets

I'm trying to create a peer to peer message app, I understand I need each instance of the app to be both a server and a client as I've got for the below code but I'm wondering how to set up the ports, can I send and receive messages on the same port?

The below code is one instance of the app, I can communicate with another version but I have to set the other version to send messages on port 9000 and receive messages on 6190. This won't work going forward as how would a third user connect?

Current situation:
User 1: Receives on 9000, sends on 6190
User 2: Receives on 6190, sends on 9000

```
import socket
import time
import threading

global incoming
def server_socket(): #call server_socket() in build method?
    try:
        s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        s.bind(('', 9000))
        s.listen(1)
        host_name = socket.gethostname()
        ip_address = socket.gethostbyname(host_name)
        print("IP address is: ", ip_address)
    except socket.error as e:
        print("Socket Error !!", "Unable To Setup Local Socket. Port In Use")

    while True:
        conn, addr = s.accept()

        incoming_ip = str(addr[0])
        data = conn.recv(4096)
        data = data.decode('utf-8')
        print("message recieved is: ", data)
        conn.close()

    s.close()


def client_send_message():

        message = "Hello World"
        message = message.encode('utf-8')
        c = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

        try:
            c.connect(("127.0.0.1", 6190))
        except Exception as e:
            print("Connection Refused", "The Address You Are Trying To Reach Is Currently Unavailable")

        try:
            c.send(message)
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)

        c.close()

t = threading.Thread(target=server_socket)
t.start()
for i in range(5):
    time.sleep(30)
    client_send_message()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You currently use TCP and with this design you need a separat socket for each client. You can exchange data on this socket in both directions though. More common for peer to peer networks is UDP: here you can use a single socket to [recvfrom](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.socket.recvfrom) data from arbitrary clients and [sendto](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.socket.sendto) data to arbitrary clients.

Comment: Ah ok, I will look into UDP and modify my code to that, thanks